# Using sed on specific fields or columns

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with fields that are separated with colons (These are all fake numbers/names btw so no need to worry about confidentiality). What I want to accomplish is to make the last column look more like a money value i.e. have thousand separators and a dollar sign in front.

```
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:126000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:268500
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Ephram Hardy:293-259-5395:235 CarltonLane, Joliet, IL 73858:8/12/20:56700
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, Duluth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
Jose Santiago:385-898-8357:38 Fife Way, Abilene, TX 39673:1/5/58:95600
Karen Evich:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:7/25/53:85100
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Lesley Kirstin:408-456-1234:4 Harvard Square, Boston, MA 02133:4/22/62:52600
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245700
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:3/19/35:22350
Sir Lancelot:837-835-8257:474 Camelot Boulevard, Bath, WY 28356:5/13/69:24500
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Tommy Savage:408-724-0140:1222 Oxbow Court, Sunnyvale, CA 94087:5/19/66:34200
Vinh Tranh:438-910-7449:8235 Maple Street, Wilmington, VM 29085:9/23/63:68900
William Kopf:846-836-2837:6937 Ware Road, Milton, PA 93756:9/21/46:43500
Yukio Takeshida:387-827-1095:13 Uno Lane, Ashville, NC 23556:7/1/29:57000
Zippy Pinhead:834-823-8319:2356 Bizarro Ave., Farmount, IL 84357:1/1/67:89500
```

Is there any way to do this with sed? If I could just single out that last column and ignore what comes before it I feel like I could easily do something like

```
sed 's/^/$/'
```

to add the $ sign to the beginning

My expected output would be:

```
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:$126,000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:$268,500
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:$14,500
... etc
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want to have the same output just adding a '$' to the beginning of the last field and including thousand separators. For example : 56211 would be $56,211. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: If ONLY there was a tool that was specifically designed to operate on columns and actually knew about numbers/thouands. A solution using anything else would just be **AWK**ward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this.

```
$ sed 's/.\{3\}$/,&/;s/[^:]*$/\$&/' file
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:$126,000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:$268,500
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:$14,500
Ephram Hardy:293-259-5395:235 CarltonLane, Joliet, IL 73858:8/12/20:$56,700
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, Duluth, MN 23850:4/12/23:$780,900
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:$23,400
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:$45,000
Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:$58,900
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:$25,000
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:$85,100
Jose Santiago:385-898-8357:38 Fife Way, Abilene, TX 39673:1/5/58:$95,600
Karen Evich:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:7/25/53:$85,100
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:$58,200
Lesley Kirstin:408-456-1234:4 Harvard Square, Boston, MA 02133:4/22/62:$52,600
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:$35,200
Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:$245,700
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:$123,500
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:3/19/35:$22,350
Sir Lancelot:837-835-8257:474 Camelot Boulevard, Bath, WY 28356:5/13/69:$24,500
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:$20,300
Tommy Savage:408-724-0140:1222 Oxbow Court, Sunnyvale, CA 94087:5/19/66:$34,200
Vinh Tranh:438-910-7449:8235 Maple Street, Wilmington, VM 29085:9/23/63:$68,900
William Kopf:846-836-2837:6937 Ware Road, Milton, PA 93756:9/21/46:$43,500
Yukio Takeshida:387-827-1095:13 Uno Lane, Ashville, NC 23556:7/1/29:$57,000
Zippy Pinhead:834-823-8319:2356 Bizarro Ave., Farmount, IL 84357:1/1/67:$89,500
```

Comment: I want to leave the output as it was just with the $ and commas.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by the above comment.

Comment: He wants columns 1-4 from the original output, plus the munged output you show for column 5 (if I counted correctly: columns 1..N-1 and column N).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.. OR `sed 's/:\([^:]*\)\([^:]\{3\}\)$/:\$\1,\2/' file`

Comment: Try it when the number is in the millions, e.g. 1260000 - the desired output would presumably be $1,260,000 not $1260,000.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, simplicity, robustness and every other desirable quality of good software, just use awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$NF=sprintf("$%\047d",$NF)} 1' file
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:$126,000
Barbara Kertz:385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/1/46:$268,500
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:$14,500
```

Try the currently-accepted sed and this awk solutions when the last field has 1 more digit:

```
$ cat file
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:1260000

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$NF=sprintf("$%\047d",$NF)} 1' file
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:$1,260,000

$ sed 's/.\{3\}$/,&/;s/[^:]*$/\$&/' file
Arthur Putie:923-835-8745:23 Wimp Lane, Kensington, DL 38758:8/31/69:$1260,000
```